# Generic finite subgroups, associated to small finite fields, of reductive algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, characteristic-p

Theorem 1 of [LS] [Liebeck and Seitz - On the subgroup structure of exceptional groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-98-02121-7) says:

> Let $X = X(q)$ be a quasisimple group of Lie type in characteristic $p$, and suppose that $X < G$, where $G$ is a simple adjoint algebraic group of exceptional type, also in characteristic $p$.  Assume that [$q$ is large].  Then … there is a closed connected subgroup $\overline X$ of $G$ containing $X$, such that every $X$-invariant subspace of the Lie algebra $L(G)$ is also $\overline X$-invariant ….

[LS] emphasises that the condition is only on $q$, not on $p$; that is, it is OK for the characteristic $p$ to be small, as long as we take a large power of it (usually $q > 9$).  Subgroups $X$ as described are called generic.  The much more recent [Litterick - On non-generic finite subgroups of exceptional algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/1207) justifies the restriction to non-generic groups by saying that the generic case is well understood, and points to [LS], which I take indirectly to be indicating that [LS] remains the state of the art.

What, if anything, is known about generic subgroups, in the above sense, for small $q$, especially in the spirit of the quoted Theorem 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of the art for subgroups $\operatorname{PSL}_2(q)$, which constitute most of the cases where $q > 9$ in [LS], is now given by David Craven's Memoir [Maximal $\operatorname{PSL}_2$ Subgroups of Exceptional Groups of Lie Type](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/1355) ([arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07469)). For maximal subgroups, complete information for groups of type $F_4$ and $E_6$ is given in another preprint [The Maximal Subgroups of the Exceptional Groups $F_4(q)$, $E_6(q)$ and $^2E_6(q)$ and Related Almost Simple Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04869) of Craven. The case where $X(q)$ has untwisted rank more than $\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{rank}(G)$ (but arbitrary $q$) is given by Liebeck and Seitz in [Maximal Subgroups of Large Rank in Exceptional Groups of Lie Type](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024610704006179).

In all, this leaves a very small number of subgroup types; I'm not sure anyone has worried about the remaining cases explicitly.

Comment: Thank you!  Given Liebeck and Seitz's work handling maximal positive-dimensional subgroups, which involves a lot of careful computations down to $q = 2$ and $q = 3$, which as I understand it was backed up by considerable `WeightCompare`-aided computation, I thought someone might have found a way to reduce these small cases to something that could have been handled by exhaustive search.  Is the expectation that that's not possible, or just that no-one's been interested in doing it?

Comment: I would very much expect it to be do-able now, with a combination of the "feasible character" methods of my PhD thesis/Memoir and Craven's notion of "pressure" to bring in unipotent classes - In fact this is what most of the progress since then has done, more or less. I think it is mostly a lack of interest that hasn't closed the gap (caveat: I have been working on other things and may well have missed recent papers on this).